# Dygraphs, comma as decimal separator

Tags: decimal, dygraphs, separator

I need to plot CSV file with dygraphs but my CSV files use comma as decimal separator.

Format is:

```
12,46;35,26;5,19
```

How can I change decimal separator from . to , in dygraphs?

Input file is given like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "values.csv", // path to CSV file
    {}          // options
  );
```

Comment: Did you tried using `replace(/,/g, ".")` before CSV parsing ?

Comment: How to to that? I added an example how file values.csv is given to dygraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to translate the file content, a possible way is to :

- get the file using XMLHttpRequest (like Dygraph does)
- tranform the content replacing "," with "."
  Next the modified CSV could be given to Dygraph.

This could be achieve with :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    // got the file
    var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    // modify content
    var data = data.replace(/,/g, ".").replace(/;/g, "\n");
    // create the graph with modified data
    new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),data);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","values.csv",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```